# How can align Primefaces datatable left which is inside a Tab?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I have this code ...

```
<p:tab title="Explore More" >
                    <ui:insert name="sideMenu">
                        <ui:include src="../ST/InterestingNumberList.xhtml" />

                    </ui:insert>
```

and

> InterestingNumberList.xhtml

Contain a Datatable. How can i align this whole Datatable left side inside Tab?My Interesting Numberlist page

```
<div class="col1" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <h:form prependId="false">
        <p:dataTable id="companyList" rows="10" style="text-align:left"
            value="${bean_numbers_list}" var="num_feature">
            <p:column  >
                <h:outputLink styleClass="morelinks"
                    value="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/topStocks/${num_feature.name}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{num_feature.shortDesc}" />
                    <f:ajax event="click" immediate="true" />
                </h:outputLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Screen i added red rectangle on the listbox which i will want to aligh left.
[image]

Comment: Start seeing your resulting HTML/CSS client side and you'll see what you need to do.

Comment: could you post the relevant pieces of your InterestingNumberList.xhtml page?

Comment: i added the code of that file

Comment: Please show a real SSCCE instead of carelessly stripped pieces which doesn't expose the concrete problem at all when being copypasted into a blank test page. The datatable is by default namely on 100% width, so there's basically nothing to left-align. Your concrete problem is caused elsewhere. You should provide **exactly** the code which would expose the concrete problem in its entirety when being fully copypasted into a blank test page, *without* the need to alter the code in order to get it to compile and run.

Comment: i added screen shot but did not get any answer